# Whats wrong with my Pivot Table VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've added code that I found on here to create a worksheet and populate it with a pivot table. The worksheet gets created every time, but the pivot table does not. No errors messages. Thoughts?

I've tried removing spaces from worksheet names, adding more detailed definitions (from similar codes I found on here)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("MBPivotTable").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets("MB Evaluation")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "MBPivotTable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set PSheet = Worksheets("MBPivotTable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("MB Raw Data")

    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = Worksheets("MB Raw Data").PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MBPivotTable")
```

I would expect a new worksheet named MBPivotTable to be created with a Pivot Table in it. Instead, just the worksheet is created without a pivot table, and no error messages. FYI, I didn't add the entire code here because I have to imagine the error is in this portion, which is why you don't see the "End Sub" portion, but it is there in the full code.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is hiding the problem.  Comment that out and re-run your code.

Comment: Possible error: it's recommended to use a `String` for the `SourceData` argument: from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create): When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string

Comment: Ok I removed the "On Error Resume Next" part and the first error came back in the Set PCache line. I fixed that and now there's an error in the "Set PTable" line that i'm not seeing.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: "Run-time roor 1004:This command requires at least two rows of source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one row. Try the following" It then goes on to explain what to do if youre creating a pivot table, but its cut off in the msgbox so I cant tell what it says.

Comment: Maybe share what `LastRow` and `LastCol` are, as well as your updated `Set PCache` line.

Comment: here is the lastrow last col (I haven't changed that so its the same as above)                                                                                                             'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Comment: Here is the new pcache                                                                                                       Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Comment: You didn't change the `PRange` to a `String`. Though I'm curious, what is the address of that range?

Comment: The address for Prange is a worksheet called MB Raw Data (defined as Dsheet). I tried a few different variations of string and what you see above, and all are giving the same runtime error.